# Send multiple mail is not happening

Tags: php, mysql, email

Thanks in advance to all. I am designing a shopping cart in php and mysql. I want to send order confirmation email to the client and also to admin registered email-id. My email function is

```
      function send_mail($address,$subject,$message,$path){
      global $error;    
       $mail = new PHPMailer();
       //$mail->isSMTP();
        //$mail->SMTPDebug = 1;               // Enable verbose debug output
       //$mail->SMTPAuth = true; 
      //$mail->SMTPSecure ='ssl' ;
      //$mail->Host ="smtp.mail.yahoo.com";
      //$mail->Port = '465'; // use 587 also
     //$mail->Username = "";
     //$mail->Password = "";

    $mail->setFrom("sales@dressncrafts.com", "Dress N Crafts");
    $mail->addReplyTo("sales@dressncrafts.com", "Dress N Crafts");

    $mail->addAddress($address);    // Add a recipient
    $mail->Subject    = $subject;
   //$mail->AltBody    = $message; // optional, comment out and test
   $mail->MsgHTML($message);
   $mail->addAttachment($path);      // attachment

   $send = $mail->send();

  $mail->clearAddresses();
  $mail->clearAttachments(); 

  if(!$send) {
    return FALSE;
   } else {
    return TRUE;
    }  

    }
```

Now the problem is when I triggered the function to send mail, only customer email is sent but admin email is not sending. I have tried to input sleep function, use the same function in a different name, but all gone in vain. The absurd thing is that if I changed the order of the mail, only customer mail is sending. Please help me to solve the problem. thank you. the very code is

```
    $message = "Hello $name, your order (order number:$ordernumber) has been 
    placed on the date $date with the following details."
    .'<br><br><center>'.$body.'</center><br>'."Subtotal:Rs. 
    $subtotal".'<br>'."Delivery Charges:Extra".'<br>'."Total:Rs. 
    $total".'<br>'.

    "Your order is under process and the invoice is attached with the 
     mail.Please find it.".'<br><br>'.
    "Thanking you".'<br>'.$about->getShopname();

     $subject = "Successful order";
    $cust_mail=send_mail($email,$subject,$message,$invpath);
   $shopsubject = "New Order";

  $shop_email= $about->getEmail();
 $shop_mail= send_mail($shop_email,$shopsubject,"New order has arrived, find 
 the attachment",$invpath);


  if($shop_mail==TRUE && $cust_mail==TRUE){   
  foreach($cartresult as $cres)
  {
     $cart->setIdcart($cres->idcart);
     $cart->deleteCart();
   }

  redirect("../checkout.php?plsord=TRUE&cust={$cust_mail}&shop=
  {$shop_mail}");

       } 
     else {


         foreach($cartresult as $cres)
        {
        $cart->setIdcart($cres->idcart);
        $cart->deleteCart();
         } 
     redirect("../checkout.php?plsord=TRUE&some=false&cust=
     {$cust_mail}&shop={$shop_mail}");    

      }
```

Comment: Did you validate that $shop_email has the correct email address? Also check the mail sending library doc to see if you can turn on debugging or something which provides you details on what error occurred.

Comment: It is a valid email id. I have tried the debugging method but no error is happening only mail is not sending.